# Wrong version of androidx.fragment:fragment used

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-fragments, androidx

I have issue with performing update of libs in my project. I have bumped everything and mostly seems alright. However issue is with lib **androidx.fragment:fragment**. According to dependency tree it should be resolved to 1.5.4.
Issue is that in tree **MyActivity -> AppCompatActivity -> FragmentActivity** it turns out that for AppCompatActivity *androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1* is used, however for FragmentActivity *androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0* . While inspecting another project built with same stack and same version of libs it turns out,that FragmentActivity is resolved as version 1.1.0 .

Top level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.7.22'
        rxJavaVersion = '2.2.21'
        rxKotlinVersion = '2.4.0'
        rxAndroidVersion = '2.1.1'
        bindingLibraryVersion = '4.0.0'
        koinVersion = '3.1.5'
        retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
        navComponents = "2.5.3"
        corutinesVersion = '1.6.4'
        androidLifecycleVersion = '2.5.1'
        roomVersion = '2.4.3'
        appCenterSdkVersion = '3.3.0'
        playServicesVersion = '21.0.1'
        workVersion = '2.7.1'
        firebaseBOM = '31.1.0'
        cameraxVersion = "1.1.0"
        moshiVersion = "1.13.0"
        stetho = '1.6.0'
        ZxingVersion = "3.4.1"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navComponents"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "$kotlinVersion"
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        androidVersionCode = getVersionCode()
        androidVersionName = getVersionName()
        storePassword = getStorePassword()
        minSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        compileSdkVersion = 33
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()   //left due to shipbook. Cannot find proper repository for it
    }
}
```

main module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':data')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$androidLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$androidLifecycleVersion"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navComponents"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navComponents"

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'

    implementation "me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter:$bindingLibraryVersion"
    implementation "me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:$bindingLibraryVersion"

    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koinVersion"
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion", {
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-extensions'
    })

    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:$stetho"
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:$stetho"


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$corutinesVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:${corutinesVersion}"

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebaseBOM")

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$cameraxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$cameraxVersion"  //no newer version can applied for now due to issues with compatibility

    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"

    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.2'
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'
    implementation "com.google.zxing:core:$ZxingVersion"

    implementation ('io.shipbook.shipbooksdk:shipbooksdk:1.6.0', {
        exclude group: 'androidx.fragment', module: 'fragment'
    })

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
}
```

I have been trying cleaning project, removing from gradle directory library files for version 1.0.0 but it keeps coming back. I have no idea what to look for. I have checked dependency tree resolved by gradle but there is nothing about fragment in version 1.0.0 or 1.1.0

I need latest version of **FragmentActivity** to use required by me version of **ComponentActivity** for some of its new code.

EDIT
Adding

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.4'
```

also don't change anything. Removing *suspiscious* exclude for shipbook also brings nothing.

EDIT 2:
this is FragmentActivity which I don't want:
[image: androidx.fragment.fragment:1.0.0]

and this is which I need:

[image: androidx.fragment.fragment:1.1.0]

Comment: Why are you doing that " exclude group: 'androidx.fragment', module: 'fragment'"?

Comment: It was just a guess to not use by accident old dependency from this lib. Done as part of experimenting what could cause wrong version. It don't change anything, especially as this is just remote logging library

Comment: I have even removed that statement and effect is still same

Comment: Are you sure you're reading your dependency tree right? The current *appcompat* release has a dependency on version *1.3.6* of the *fragment* library, it's unlikely it would even work if you could force Gradle to resolve it to *1.0.0* instead (Gradle resolves version conflicts by using the *highest requested version*). If you want *1.5.4*, add the dependency explicitly and that's what you'll get! `FragmentContainerView` got a `getFragment()` method in *1.4.0* - see if you have access to that

Comment: I'm pretty sure. As it is not about dependency tree reading as the sources Android studio is showing me with version displayed on window title. I'm looking for correct version of FragmentActivity which imports Component Activity from activity package to contain backpresseddispatcher

Comment: @cactustictacs I have added screenshots with informations I'm referring. From those downloaded sources I know that FragmentActivity in version 1.0.0 imports different package of ComponentActivity than in version 1.1.0

Comment: I don't know what sources you're looking at, but you can run the `dependencies` Gradle task (Gradle tab on the side of the window, elephant icon to run a task) to see your dependency tree and how it's resolved. e.g. for a project I have open, under the `appcompat` dependency it has the dependency `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6 -> 1.5.4` which means `appcompat` was pulling in version *1.3.6*, but the version actually being *used* is *1.5.4* (because another dependency specifies that higher version, in this case because it's been added explicitly in `build.gradle`). That's what gets built

Comment: More info here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

Comment: Yes, I have been running this. Those sources are explicit what has been resolved. Yes, according to gradle dependencies it is resolved to 1.5.4, but somehow is used 1.0.0 . Sources are most explicit as I'm just opening superclass in AndroidStudio and on toolbar I can see version. I can see also imports which are not one which I need (wrong package for import ComponentActivity)

Comment: Also if I remove from gradle cache 1.0.0 package of fragment when I build this project it appears again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identified issue was dependencies from Firebase BOM package and Play Services Location defined in data layer (clean architecture -> layer responsible only for handling database and API connections). Solution was to exclude fragment dependency from their imports

```
 implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesLocationVersion", {
        exclude group: 'androidx.fragment'
    })

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebaseBOMVersion")
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging', {
        exclude group: 'androidx.fragment'
    })
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, tried to exclude the group, as you suggested but no luck. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: You can check other libs which are using androidx fragment dependency. Maybe on latest versions it have been patched also