# facing unResolvedReference error when using onBackPressedDispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, onbackpressed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7MU9.png)
kotlin version : 1.6.1
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2" // I used 1.6.1 too but no use
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.1"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1"

While taking ctrl reference from the base activity : I encountered similar issue described here
[Wrong version of androidx.fragment:fragment used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74624788/wrong-version-of-androidx-fragmentfragment-used)

I need to resolve onBackPressed deprecation with onBackpressedDispatcher

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment you should call like this

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
  this, // LifecycleOwner
  callback
)
```

Fore more details refer : [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher)