'by viewModels' not recognized in AppcompactActivty
When I try to initialize viewmodel in an Activity which extends ComponentActivity, I can use "by viewModels(..)" . However if I try to instantiate the same in an activity that extents AppCompactActivity, it remains unresolved.
I checked the source code of 'by viewModel', looks like its only applicable on ComponentActivity,
public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModels(
    noinline extrasProducer: (() -> CreationExtras)? = null,
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM> {
    val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }

    return ViewModelLazy(
        VM::class,
        { viewModelStore },
        factoryPromise,
        { extrasProducer?.invoke() ?: this.defaultViewModelCreationExtras }
    )
}

Is there a way in which I can also use this function under AppCompactActivity?
I have tried adding the following dependencies:
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.3")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.3")

implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.8.1")
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")

implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.3")


viewModels is indeed only defined for ComponentActivity, but AppCompactActivity extends from ComponentActivity, so it is available there too, everything shoud work, I cannot reproduce the problem you have. Please provide a [mre] if the problem persists.

AppCompactActivity extends from ComponentActivity from androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity(). The viewModels is available in  ComponentActivity from androidx.activity.ComponentActivity. Hence its not avaialble

Both ComponentActivities are from different package

androidx.activity.ComponentActivity extends androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity, but that doesn't matter because
AppCompatActivity extends androidx.activity.ComponentActivity and viewModels is also defined on androidx.activity.ComponentActivity. I just tried it out (again) with the dependencies you provided and everything compiles just fine, as expected. You need to [edit] your question and provide a [mre] that we can use to reproduce the problem.

I believe the issue is with the dependencies. I created a new project and it worked fine. My old project 'FragmentActivity' extends "ComponentActivity" directly from androidx core, however my new project "FragmentActivity" extends "ComponentActivity" from package androidx.activity which in turn extends "ComponentActivity" from androidx core

@Leviathan Can you please help me out, My project is using two versions of androidx.fragment:fragment 1.0.0 and 1.6.2 , If I can manage to make it use only the latest, it will solve the issue. However there are too many libraries which are internally using 1.0.0, even after updating those libraries, I am still unable to completely remove 1.0.0

You can rewrite your question to focus on that aspect. You have to make sure to include all necessary information for us to reproduce your problem by providing a [mre]. That means you would need to post your relevant build files. You can [edit] your question and remove everything concerning viewModels and instead ask about how you can make your build use version 1.6.2 of androidx.fragment:fragment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74624788/wrong-version-of-androidx-fragmentfragment-used

Got a similar issue, deleting this question. Thanks
